# Entity Framework Include relations on derived types for Table per Hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I `Include` the relationships of properties on a collection where the collection type is of a Table per Hierarchy design and the relationships are defined on the derived types with lazy loading disabled?

What I am trying to avoid is to declare the relationships on the base type or to have multiple DB calls to retrieve the relationships. Is there a way around this?

## Attempts and Errors

I have tried using `OfType` but receive this message.

> System.ArgumentException - The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I have tried using `as` but receive this error

> System.InvalidOperationException - A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Sandbox.TPHMcve.Person' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Buildings'.

## Example

*Please do not focus on the business details of this silly example, it is an mcve to illustrate the error I am receiving. My actual project has nothing to do with schools / school systems etc.*

### Structure

- A school in a University has Persons
- A Person is either Student or Teacher
- Student has zero or more course books on loan
- Teacher can be assigned as the care taker / guardian for one or more campus buildings

### Code

**SchoolService.cs**

*This is the actual code of interest that produces the Exceptions*

```
public sealed class SchoolService
{
    private readonly UniversityDbContext _dbContext;
    public SchoolService(UniversityDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public School GetSchoolAndPeopleWithDetails_OfType(int schoolId)
    {
        return _dbContext.Schools.Where(x => x.SchoolId == schoolId)
            .Include(x => x.EntitiesOfSchool.OfType<Teacher>().Select(y => y.Buildings))
            .Include(x => x.EntitiesOfSchool.OfType<Student>().Select(y => y.BooksOnLoan))
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
    public School GetSchoolAndPeopleWithDetails_Cast(int schoolId)
    {
        return _dbContext.Schools.Where(x => x.SchoolId == schoolId)
            .Include(x => x.EntitiesOfSchool.Select(y => (y as Teacher).Buildings))
            .Include(x => x.EntitiesOfSchool.Select(y => (y as Student).BooksOnLoan))
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**Entities.cs**

```
public sealed class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> EntitiesOfSchool { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public School PrimarySchool { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Teacher : Person
{
    public ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Student : Person
{
    public ICollection<CourseBook> BooksOnLoan { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Building
{
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Teacher AssignedGuardian { get; set; }
    public int GuardianId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CourseBook
{
    public int CourseBookId { get; set; }
    public int BookNumber { get; set; }
    public Student AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public int? AssignedToId { get; set; }
}
```

**EntityMappings.cs** *does not include Building or CourseBook mapping types as they are not relevant*

```
public sealed class SchoolMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<School>
{
    public SchoolMap()
    {
        ToTable("Schools");
        HasKey(x => x.SchoolId);
        Property(x => x.SchoolId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().IsUnicode(true).HasMaxLength(200);
        HasMany(x => x.EntitiesOfSchool).WithRequired(x => x.PrimarySchool).HasForeignKey(person => person.SchoolId);
    }
}

public sealed class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        ToTable("Persons");
        HasKey(x => x.PersonId);
        Property(x => x.PersonId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().IsUnicode(true).HasMaxLength(256);
        Map<Teacher>(configuration => configuration.Requires("PersonType").HasValue(1));
        Map<Student>(configuration => configuration.Requires("PersonType").HasValue(2));
    }
}

public sealed class TeacherMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Teacher>
{
    public TeacherMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Buildings).WithRequired(x => x.AssignedGuardian).HasForeignKey(x => x.GuardianId);
    }
}
public sealed class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.BooksOnLoan).WithOptional(x => x.AssignedTo).HasForeignKey(x => x.AssignedToId);
    }
}
```

**UniversityDbContext.cs**

```
public sealed class UniversityDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UniversityDbContext() : base("Name=default")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // disable lazy loading
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SchoolMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeacherMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
    }

    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
}
```

**Sql code for table DDE and seed of  data.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schools](
    [SchoolId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] Nvarchar (200) not null
CONSTRAINT [PK_Schools] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SchoolId] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolId] [int] not null,
    [PersonType] [int] not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(256) not null
CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buildings](
    [BuildingId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(200) not null,
    [GuardianId] [int] not null,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Buildings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BuildingId] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseBooks](
    [CourseBookId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BookNumber] varchar(200) not null,
    [AssignedToId] [int] null,
CONSTRAINT [PK_CourseBooks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseBookId] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Schools_Persons] FOREIGN KEY([SchoolId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schools] ([SchoolId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Buildings] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Persons_Buildings] FOREIGN KEY([GuardianId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Persons] ([PersonId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseBooks] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Persons_CourseBooks] FOREIGN KEY([AssignedToId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Persons] ([PersonId])



INSERT INTO Schools (Name) values (N'Business'), (N'Education')
INSERT INTO Persons (Name, PersonType, SchoolId) values ('Eddy',1, 1), ('Fran',1, 1), ('Joe',2, 1), ('Kim',2, 1)
INSERT INTO Buildings (Name, GuardianId) values (N'Offsite staff', 1), (N'Main Business Building', 1)
INSERT INTO CourseBooks(AssignedToId, BookNumber) values (3, 'Course A book 1'),(3, 'Course C book 31')
```

Comment: This is EF limitation which is not solved even in the latest EF Core. So no, there is no way to workaround this at `IQueryable<T>` (`Include`) level. The only known solution is materialization and explicit loading.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev for taking a look. Too bad, that would have been nice. Do you know if there is a feature request already that I can tack my name on to? If not I will create one.

Comment: For EF Core I think it's tracked by [Query: Support Include/ThenInclude for navigation on derived type #3910](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3910) and is scheduled for v2.1.0 From the comments under the link, looks like no such enhancement is planned for EF6 :-(

Comment: Thank you again @IvanStoev. I have created a [feature request for EF6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/403) and added a reference link back to the link you posted above for EF Core. I won't hold my breath though as I am aware that EF6 is really in a maintenance mode with new features targeted primarily in EF Core.